# Can someone explain why FOR and WHILE loop have different output in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was learning javascript, working with loops i ran into this problem.
the while loop is written to do exactly what the for loop does, but to my surprise the output differs. Thanks...

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    console.log(i);
}

// output -> 1 2 3

var j = 1;
while (j < 4){
    console.log(j);
    j += 1;
}
// output -> 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: There is no difference. http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/8gsw01f9/1/

Comment: Your output can not have 4 in the while loop because you stop the loop before it becomes 4.

Comment: It seems that the basic premise of the question is flawed. If it is indeed, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I was surprise at the output my self, but on codecademy where im taking the js course that's what it outputs.

Comment: I think the broken version may have been: var j = 0;
while (j++ < 4){
    console.log(j);
}

Answer (score 0):

To get the one off error you need to change the loop to increment before the output.

```
var j = 0;
while (j < 4){
    j += 1;
    console.log(j);
}
// output -> 1 2 3 4
```

Note: this is not an answer to the question, which appears to have already been fixed. But because code is presented it is posted as an answer instead of a comment, so the code can be read easily.

The classic example of one off is.

```
var j = 0;
while (j < 4){
    console.log(++j);
}
```

Which can happen in some cases using j++ these incrementals need special attention that is why many prefer the j += 1 syntax.

```
var j = 0;
while (j++ < 4){
    console.log(j);
}
// outputs 1 2 3 4 the problem is the comparison takes place before j is incremented.
```